# Permission error in Python, when working with audiosegment in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, permissions, playback, temp

I wrote a short text to play the audio file.
But when running, the program gives error permission.
I noticed that every time I run the program, the name of the file that has the permission error is different
This file is in the temp path
I checked this path and there was no file with that name

Program text:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

try:
     song=AudioSegment.from_wav("myfile.wav")

except IOError:
    print("can not open file")

try:
    play(song)
except IOError:
    print("can not play file")
```

The output of the program was as follows:

```
My Project Python/my project python/play wav.py"
can not play file
```

When I try the program without the block Try: , the output is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\My Project Python\my project python\play wav.py", line 7, in <module>
    play(song)
  File "C:\Users\H&M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pydub\playback.py", line 71, in play    _play_with_ffplay(audio_segment)
  File "C:\Users\H&M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pydub\playback.py", line 15, in _play_with_ffplay
    seg.export(f.name, "wav")
  File "C:\Users\H&M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 867, in export
    out_f, _ = _fd_or_path_or_tempfile(out_f, 'wb+')
  File "C:\Users\H&M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 60, in _fd_or_path_or_tempfile
    fd = open(fd, mode=mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\H&M\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp7t2o2ta1.wav'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This also works:

```
def _play_with_ffplay(seg):
PLAYER = get_player_name()
with NamedTemporaryFile("w+b", suffix=".wav") as f:
    f.close()
    seg.export(f.name, "wav")
    subprocess.call([PLAYER, "-nodisp", "-autoexit", "-hide_banner", f.name])
```

Just close the file with the f.close() command

Comment: How does this work?
Can someone explain this

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for this question, but it is not an optimized answer

```
def _play_with_ffplay(seg):
  PLAYER = get_player_name()
  with NamedTemporaryFile("w+b", suffix=".wav") as f:
     fileName = f.name  
  seg.export(fileName, "wav") 
  subprocess.call([PLAYER, "-nodisp", "-autoexit", "-hide_banner", fileName])
  os.remove(fileName)
```

I made these changes in the  playback.py file and got the answer . [link](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/209)